# python: how to check the integer input by user match the item in the list of not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a scenario. I have a list with ID like 
result = ['003234568', '000000001', '123456789'].

I want to ask user to input ID and loop until ID is unique.
I try this one but doesn't get expected output.

```
result = ['003234568', '000000001', '123456789'].
playersID = int(input ("Enter ID of the player: "))
while playersID in result:
    print ("players id already exist, please enter new one")
    playersID = int(input ("Enter ID of the player: "))
```

I don't want to use any other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` is a list of strings and you are taking input as integer, that's why `playersID` is never in `result`. You need to change the input lines to the following:

Change

```
playersID = int(input("Enter ID of the player: "))
```

To

```
playersID = input("Enter ID of the player: ")
```

Comment: Thank you Moe, but the player ID must be an integer type. How can I work for this?

Comment: You can change the list to have integers instead of strings, but integers can't have leading zeros